# Comparing TypeIds of generic type and trait object

Tags: rust

I want to add some multimaterialness to my game engine, and I have a special trait `Material: Any` for it, which can create separate pipelines.
I have collection of material types (HashMap<TypeId, Pipeline>) and collection of material objects Vec<Arc<(dyn Material + Send + Sync)>>, and methods to work with them:

```rust
pub fn create_material(
    &mut self,
    material: Arc<(dyn Material + Send + Sync)>,
) -> MaterialHandle
{
    let index = self.materials.len();
    self.materials.push(material);
    return MaterialHandle::new(index);
}
```

```rust
pub fn bind_material<M: Material + Sync + Send>(&mut self){ 
    self.pipelines.insert(TypeId::of::<M>(), M::pipeline(&self));   
}
```

And when I process materials, I need to bind a pipeline and get (ECS) all materials of matching type. But it turns out that TypeIds of pipeline's material and gotten material are different (even though I have only one material type and instance)

```rust
for material_type in self.pipelines.keys() {
    let pipeline = self.pipelines.get(&material_type).unwrap();
    bind_pipeline(pipeline);

    for (_, (mesh, handle, transform)) in &mut world.query::<(
        &Mesh, &MaterialHandle, &Transform,
    )>(){
        let found_material = self.materials.get(handle.get()).unwrap();
        println!("Parsed material: {:?}, Object material: {:?}", *material_type, found_material.type_id()); // TypeIds are different
    }
}
```

I think it is because I am trying to compare TypeId of generic type and trait object, which is incorrent. What shall I do?

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding, but how would that `world.query` filter out entities that don't match the `material_type`? I'm not seeing the connection...

Comment: @kmdreko sorry for unclear explanation, there it only shows that types differs, but in actual code it is like `if type1 == type2 {...}`, which unfortunately is never `true`

Comment: I think `found_material` is of type `&Arc<(dyn Material + Send + Sync)>`. If that's the case, then `found_material.type_id()` would return the `TypeId` of `Arc<(dyn Material + Send + Sync)>` (because that type implements `Any` and `type_id()` takes `self` by shared reference). Try `(**found_material).type_id()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for abandoning this question. It turned out, that I tried to get TypeId of Arc wrapper, but not a material itself.

```rust
 println!("Parsed material: {:?}, Object material: {:?}", *material_type, (**found_material).type_id());
```

This works (https://github.com/konceptosociala/despero/blob/main/src/render/renderer.rs#LL294C15-L294C15)